# url and django database no object found matching the query with identical working class

Tags: python, django

I can't figure out why OfertoHome view works but not OfertoListView, They both are identical the only thing that is different is in the url.

```
class OfertoListView(ListView):
    model = Oferto
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = "ofertoj/oferto_list.html"

def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = super(OfertoListView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return context


class OfertoHome(ListView):
    model = Oferto
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = "ofertoj/oferto_list.html"

def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = super(OfertoHome,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return context
```

urls.py

```
    url(
regex=r"^listview/$",
view=OfertoListView.as_view(),
name="oferto_listview"
),

url(
regex=r"^$",
view = OfertoHome.as_view(),
name ="oferto_home"
),
```

Debug Message

```
   Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/oferto/listview/
No oferto found matching the query
```

This is my complete views.py in the app, posted because requested

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ofertoj.views

from .models import Oferto
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView, DetailView
from django.views.generic import ListView

from turtle.views import Turtle_CreateView,ActionMixin,NameSearchMixin
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin

from forms import OfertoCreateForm,OfertoUpdateForm


class OfertoCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,Turtle_CreateView):
    model = Oferto
    action = "created"
    form_class = OfertoCreateForm


class OfertoDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Oferto

class OfertoResultsView(OfertoDetailView):
    template_name = "Oferto/results.html"

class OfertoUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,ActionMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Oferto
    action = "created"
    form_class = OfertoUpdateForm

class OfertoListView(ListView):
    model = Oferto
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = "ofertoj/oferto_list.html"

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(OfertoListView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context


class OfertoHome(ListView):
    model = Oferto
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = "ofertoj/oferto_list.html"

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(OfertoHome,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

urls.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ofertoj/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from views import *

urlpatterns = patterns("",
    url(
    regex=r"^createview/$",
    view=OfertoCreateView.as_view(),
    name="oferto_createview"
    ),


    url(
    regex=r"^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$",
    view=OfertoDetailView.as_view(),
    name="oferto_detail"
    ),

    url(
    regex=r"^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$/results/$",
    view=OfertoResultsView.as_view(),
    name="oferto_results"
    ),

    url(
    regex=r"^listview/$",
    view=OfertoListView.as_view(),
    name="oferto_listview"
    ),


    url(
    regex=r"^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/updateview/$",
    view=OfertoUpdateView.as_view(),
    name="oferto_updateview"
    ),

    url(
    regex=r"^$",
    view = OfertoHome.as_view(),
    name ="oferto_home"
    ),
)
```

Comment: Can you post complete stack trace?

Comment: I don't get a stack trace, all I get is the django 404 page not found error.

Comment: Does it work if you goto 127.0.0.1:8000/listview/

Comment: No, it is not in a regex pattern in the urls      " Using the URLconf defined in tempilo.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:"

Comment: Is it the complete code that you have posted? Because code is generating custom 404 error and `ListView` doesn't generate error with this message. And one more thing, if both have same code then why to use diff views? Can use only one of them..

Comment: This is not my entire project, What files should I post? I have views,forms,urls,models.  Why have 2 similar class's,  It was a result of tinkering to find something that works.  anyways I will want a custom "home" to the app oferto that may be different than a generic listview.

Comment: And everything else seems to be working just fine

Comment: I meant about views, are they complete? In your code do check if you have raised 404 error with this message.

Comment: posted my views.py file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely picking up a detail view and looking for an Oferto with a pk or slug named `listview` which isn't found producing the 404. Please post your full urls.py to identify the conflict.

Yeah, your urls.py are resolved in order, the first that matches is the view that's processed.  In your case, the `r"^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$"` in your `oferto_detail` url matches the input "listview" in the url.  Put the `listview/$` url first and it should work correctly.

```
url(
regex=r"^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$",
view=OfertoDetailView.as_view(),
name="oferto_detail"
),

url(
regex=r"^listview/$",
view=OfertoListView.as_view(),
name="oferto_listview"
),
```